# How to get the first and last item in a group along with aggregate results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stock market tick data table. I want to group the ticks into open, high, low, close, minute bars.

note: time stamp is int hhmmssmmm so / 100000 give me one minute grouping (hhmm)

I can do a simple group and get the high and low:

```
select (min(time_stamp)/100000) as [time], max(price) as [high], min(price) as [low] from [20160104] 
where symbol = 'AAPL' and price_field = 0
group by (time_stamp/100000) order by [time]
```

I can then do an inner join on min(id) to get first price of the group:

```
select a.time_stamp / 100000 as bar_time, a.price as bar_open, b.bar_high, b.bar_low
FROM [20160104] as a
join
(
    select max(price) as bar_high, min(price) as bar_low, min(id) as first_id, max(id) as last_id
    from [20160104] 
    where symbol = 'AAPL' and price_field = 0
    group by (time_stamp / 100000)
) as b 
on b.first_id = a.id
```

I can also do the same with max(id) to get last price in the group.

But How do I get both first and last price on the same row with min(price) and max(price)?

Comment: How about [first_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) and same way last_value? If you use last_value, remember to have proper `rows` part -- and you can also do min / max without the need for join

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, please clarify

Comment: first_value returns the first row in the group (specified by column(s) / rules in `partition by`) ordered by whatever is given in `order by` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both joins in one statement, like this.  (For clarity, I moved your inner select to come first since both the joins depend on its results.)

```
select a.time_stamp / 100000 as bar_time, a.price as bar_open,
    b.bar_high, b.bar_low, c.price as bar_close
FROM 
(
    select max(price) as bar_high, min(price) as bar_low, min(id) as first_id, max(id) as last_id
    from [20160104] 
    where symbol = 'AAPL' and price_field = 0
    group by (time_stamp / 100000)
) as b
join [20160104] as a on b.first_id = a.id
join [20160104] as c on b.last_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use over() with max and min function to get the maximum and minimum value in the same row

{

```
select (min(time_stamp)/100000) as [time], max(price) OVER( PARTITION BY (time_stamp/100000) order by [time]) as [high], min(price) OVER( PARTITION BY (time_stamp/100000) order by [time]) as [low] from [20160104] where symbol = 'AAPL' and price_field = 0;
```

}

[You can get more information about over function here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql)